# Parsing one of two protobufs

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I've some C++ code that is expecting to receive one of two protobufs.  (This has occurred as an accommodation to history, not as an intentional design.)

The `ParseFromString` function returns false if it can't parse the string (I think, I haven't found authoritative documentation on that), so I try this:

```
const string epistula_stream;   // Provided.

EpistulaOld e1;
Epistula e2;
if (e1.ParseFromString(epistula_stream)) {
    // I've got an old-style Epistula, do something.
    DoSomething(e1);
} else if (e2.ParseFromString(epistula_stream)) {
    // I've got a new-style Epistula, do something.
    DoSomething(e2);
} else {
    LOG_ERROR << "That didn't work as expected.";
}
```

Unfortunately, both types of protobuf are generally able to parse serialised strings for both types of protobufs.  In other words,

```
LOG_INFO << "Old: " << e1.ParseFromString(epistula_stream);
LOG_INFO << "New: " << e2.ParseFromString(epistula_stream);
```

prints

```
Old: true
New: true
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

One option is that I initialise two separate listeners on two separate ports, and so clients are responsible for sending to the correct port.  This is less than ideal, however, since the goal is to give client code time to upgrade and not to enforce that as a big bang.

### Update 1

In the end, since I can clearly deserialise to both of the protobufs, and since this is transition code that is not intended to run in production for more than a few weeks, I simply deserialise to both, then do a few reality checks.  For example, they store timestamps at different positions, do the timestamps represent times more or less near the present?

This has a very high calculated probability of success but is hardly iron-clad.

### Update 2

The actual protobuf definitions are these:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package analytics;

message ReaderEpistula {
    enum RESource {
        RESourceUndef = 0;
        RESourceMySQL = 1;
        RESourceMongoDB = 2;
        RESourceAll = 3;  // Don't use this (normally).
    }
    int64 client_message_id = 1;
    uint64 initiator_timestamp_microseconds = 2;
    string client_id = 3;
    string acknowledge_host = 4;
    int32 acknowledge_port = 5;
    RESource source = 6;
    string table_name = 7;
    string object_id = 8;
    int64 pk_id = 9;
    int32 group_id = 10;
    string group_type = 11;
};

message AdminEpistula {
    enum AESubject {
        AESubjectUndef = 0;  // Shouldn't happen.
        AESubjectHeartbeat = 1;
        AESubjectQuit = 2;
        AESubjectAcknowledged = 3;
        AESubjectClientError = 5;
    }
    int64 client_message_id = 1;
    uint64 initiator_timestamp_microseconds = 2;
    string client_id = 3;
    AESubject subject = 4;
}

message CandyEpistula {
    int64 client_message_id = 1;
    uint64 initiator_timestamp_microseconds = 2;
    string client_id = 3;
    string acknowledge_host = 4;
    int32 acknowledge_port = 5;
    string page_name = 6;
    string page_path = 7;
    string host_name = 8;
    string publisher = 9;
    string user_id = 10;
    bool is_admin = 11;
    bool is_dev = 12;
}

message Epistula {
    oneof payload {
        ReaderEpistula reader_epistula = 1;
        AdminEpistula admin_epistula = 2;
        CandyEpistula candy_epistula = 3;
    }
}

// This is the legacy version of an Epistula.
message EpistulaOld {
    enum EpistulaSubject {
        KEpistulaSubjectUndef = 0;  // Shouldn't happen.
        KEpistulaSubjectChange = 1;
        KEpistulaSubjectQuit = 2;
        KEpistulaSubjectHeartbeat = 3;
        KEpistulaSubjectCicero = 4;
        KEpistulaSubjectAcknowledged = 5;
        KEpistulaClientError = 6;
    }
    enum EpistulaSource {
        KEspistulaSourceUndef = 0;  // Shouldn't happen.
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLCampaign = 1;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLDemographics = 2;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLSurvey = 3;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLAmalgamated = 4;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLFocusGroup = 5;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLSpine = 6;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLFocusGroupReaders = 7;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLReadableSample = 8;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLBookshelfableItem = 9;
        KEpistulaSourceMySQLMerchant = 10;
        KEpistulaSourceMongodbSyncReminder = 101;
        KEpistulaSourceMongodbSyncEvent = 102;
        KEpistulaSourceMongodbSurvey = 103;
        KEpistulaSourceMongodbCandyEvent = 104;
        // KEpistulaSourceMongodbCandyEventRegister
        DEPRECATED__KEpistulaSourceMongodbCandyEventEpubDownload = 107;
        DEPRECATED__KEpistulaSourceMongodbCandyEventViewCampaignPage = 108;
        DEPRECATED__KEpistulaSourceMongodbCandyEventViewDownloadPage = 109;
        DEPRECATED__KEpistulaSourceMongodbCandyEventsEpubCloudReaderOpen = 110;
        DEPRECATED__KEpistulaSourceMongodbCandyEventsPineappleUtm = 106;
        KEpistulaSourceMongodbCrowberryStream = 105;
        KEpistulaSourceMongodbDoNotTrack = 111;
        KEpistulaSourceCicero = 201;
        KEpistulaSourcePlinyCommandline = 202;
        KEpistulaSourcePlinyElder = 203;
        KEpistulaSourcePlinyYounger = 204;
        KEpistulaSourcePlinyComponent = 205;
        KEpistulaSourceRailsFullUpdate = 206;
    }
    enum EpistulaPhase {
        KEpistulaPhaseUndef = 0;
        KEpistulaPhaseBegin = 1;
        KEpistulaPhaseEndOK = 2;
        KEpistulaPhaseEndBad = 3;
        KEpistulaPhaseAction = 4;
    }
    EpistulaSubject subject = 1;
    EpistulaSource source = 2;
    uint64 initiator_timestamp_microseconds = 3;
    uint64 client_provided_id = 4;
    bool please_acknowledge = 5;
    bool this_is_a_test = 6;
    int32 campaign_id = 7;
    int32 reading_group_id = 8;
    string reading_group_type = 9;
    int32 user_id = 10;
    string device_id = 13;
    string variant = 16;
    string candy_event_name = 15;
    string insertion_component_name = 11;
    string insertion_host_name = 14;
    EpistulaPhase phase = 12;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the .proto files for your Epistula and EpistulaOld messages?

Comment: As Jan said, it would be good if you can share the .proto files. What I would guess right now is, since the two types are very similar, it can parse both if the fields are not defined as required but optional. Maybe, if you define the extra fields of new type(or the redundant fields of old type) as required, parsing will fail for one of the cases

Comment: Sure, pasted above.

Comment: A potential solution, but not necessarily a good one: you can add a new field, with a high field number (greater than any one in the old message), like `optional int32 protocol_version = 99;`, and require it be set by the new clients, at least for a time. This way you guarantee that you always know if it's the new format.